# search in each of the s3 bucket and see if the given folder exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the files from specific folders in s3 Buckets:

I have 4 buckets in s3 with the following names:

```
1 - 'PDF'
2 - 'TXT'
3 - 'PNG'
4 - 'JPG'
```

The folder structure for all s3 buckets looks like this:

```
1- PDF/analysis/pdf-to-img/processed/files
2- TXT/report/processed/files
3- PNG/analysis/reports/png-to-txt/processed/files
4- JPG/jpg-to-txt/empty
```

I have to check if this folder prefix `processed/files` is present in the bucket, and if it is present, I'll read the files present in those directories, else I'll ignore them.

---

**Code:**

```
buckets = ['PDF','TXT','PNG','JPG']

client = boto3.client('s3')
for i in bucket:
    result = client.list_objects(Bucket=i,Prefix = 'processed/files', Delimiter='/')
    print(result)
```

I can enter into each directory if the folder structure is same, but how can I handle this when the folder structure varies for each bucket?

Comment: you will have idea about each bucket folder structure ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is maybe a lengthy process.

```
 buckets = ['PDF','TXT','PNG','JPG']
    s3_client = getclient('s3')
    for i in buckets:
        result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket= i, Prefix='', Delimiter ='')
        contents = result.get('Contents')
        for content in contents:
            if 'processed/files/' in content.get('Key'):
                print("Do the process")
```

You can get the list of directories from the s3 bucket. If it contains the required folder do the required process.

Comment: This is shortest way to do find exact answer. Upvoting your answer. Mine was little bigger code.

Answer (score 3):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = "bucket_name"
prefix = ""

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

result = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Delimiter='/')
   for obj in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):  
       prefix = obj.get('Prefix')
       file_list = ListFiles(client,bucket_name,prefix)
       for file in file_list:
          if "processed/files" in file:
              print("Found",file)

def ListFiles(client, bucket_name, prefix):
    _BUCKET_NAME = bucket_name
    _PREFIX = prefix
    """List files in specific S3 URL"""
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket=_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=_PREFIX)

    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        #print(content)
        yield content.get('Key')
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMy6o.png)